# Chrome/Chromium input number value empty when last char is dot

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, input, chromium

In Chrome (or other Chromium browser) when I try to get a value of a number input field the value is empty when the last char is a dot (`.`).

Here is the simplest example I could think of:

```html
<input type="number" oninput="console.log(event.target.value)">
```

In Chrome when typing for example "123.45" will result in this output:

```
1
12
123

123.4
123.45
```

In Firefox I get something more like I would expect:

```
1
12
123
123    
123.4
123.45
```

Getting `valueAsNumber` instead of `value` will result in a `NaN` if the last char is dot, so no success there either.
Is there a way to get what is is the actual value of the field (or at least the value without the dot) and not something that is already parsed somehow?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Kaiido I'm a little closer as to why this happens
In my Chrome browser `navigator.languages` is set to `['en-US', 'en', 'nl']` in Firefox it's set to just `['en-US', 'en']`

This explains the difference between the 2 browsers (in my case) and why in Chrome I can use `,` as well as `.`.

But I still need a solution for the problem.
The most important thing in my case is that I need a distinction between the field being empty or some other value that somehow can't de parsed to a number. So now the question is more is there a way to get the value of what's actually being types in the field.

Comment: Same (expected) behavior with Chromium (v90, Debian 11.2) as with Firefox (v91.4 ESR)

Comment: No repro either on macOs, Chrome 96 & 99, with en-US as default locale (both OS and browser). What are your default locales?

Comment: @Kaiido That's a good one; in my case when I use a comma `,` it works as expected. Although then I'm still confused as to why I can type a dot in this field then in the first place. And why apparently I accepts the dot as a valid part when there are decimals behind it.

Comment: Indeed with a locale that uses COMMA not DOT as delimiter I get "1234" as result, as expected. The "checkValidity()" for it returns false if I use any form of delimiter - but If I add a 'step="0.1"' attribute this check becomes true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the '**step**' attribute to make it validate and use the locales delimiter.

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" oninput="console.log(event.target.value)" />
```

More information:

```
<input type="number" oninput="console.log('VAL: %s|%s|%s', this.value, this.checkValidity(), this.validationMessage)" step="0.1">
```

Entering a delimiter not used in the current locale the validity and corresponding message will indicate 'this is not a number', once more digits are entered - up to the limit of precision the **step** attribute allows - it will parse to valid values again. Your GUI should correspondingly indicate the current validity - if your code requires it to always be usable as a valid number you could save the last value that passed validation, depending on your use case.

Also consider the use of the character "e" which may be cause for a temporary invalid value!

Comment: This will still result in value being an empty string if using a dot in a locale which uses a comma.

Comment: I've added some more thoughts and code - HTH

Comment: Perfect addition! with the `checkValidity()` I can make a distinction between an empty field and a NaN value

Comment: Checking for `validity.badInput` in my case is an even better solution!